# Why are uri paths not redirected to index.php by my .htaccess only for https / ssl?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, xampp

I am getting an 404 error only for HTTPs when the URL has a uri path that must be redirected to index.php for proper routing.

*Examples:*

```
200 => https://localhostcl.idinteractive.co/ 
200 => http://localhostcl.idinteractive.co/ 
200 => http://localhostcl.idinteractive.co/login 
404 => https://localhostcl.idinteractive.co/login (this should be redirect by the htaccess below to index.php). Why is it not?
```

*Browser says...*

> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.

*Apache error logs say...*

> [Wed Feb 19 12:59:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.22] File does not
>   exist: C:/DATA/IDInteractive/IDdashboard/dev/cl/login

**.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^wwwroot.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.html
</IfModule>
```

**http-vhost.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen *:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.22:80>
    <Directory "C:/DATA/IDInteractive/IDdashboard/dev/cl">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +Includes
                Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin xxx@taylormadetraffic.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/DATA/IDInteractive/IDdashboard/dev/cl"
    ServerPath "C:/DATA/IDInteractive/IDdashboard/dev/cl"
    ServerName localhostcl.idinteractive
    ServerAlias localhostcl.idinteractive.co
    ErrorLog "logs/idinteractive-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/idinteractive-access.log" combined
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-mapp-php5 .php
        AddHandler application/x-mapp-php5 .php     
        AddHandler php-cgi .php
        AddHandler server-parsed .html
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen *:443

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
</IfModule>
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLMutex default
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.22:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/DATA/IDInteractive/IDdashboard/dev/cl"
    ServerName localhostcl.idinteractive
    ServerAlias localhostcl.idinteractive.co
    ServerAdmin xxx@taylormadetraffic.com
    ErrorLog "logs/idinteractive-ssl-error.log"
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        CustomLog "logs/idinteractive-ssl-access.log" combined
    </IfModule>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"    
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>    
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "logs/ssl_request.log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-mapp-php5 .php
        AddHandler application/x-mapp-php5 .php     
        AddHandler php-cgi .php
        AddHandler server-parsed .html
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm    
</VirtualHost>  
</IfModule>
```

**windows host file:**

```
127.0.0.22  localhostcl.idinteractive.co
```

Comment: Is `login` a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `<Directory>` container in your ssl vhost as well:

```
<Directory "C:/DATA/IDInteractive/IDdashboard/dev/cl">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +Includes
            Allow from all
</Directory>
```

otherwise `AllowOverride` won't be set to `All` in the ssl vhost but it *is* set in the non-SSL vhost.